# Removing elements by id using event Javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of phones thats displaying as ul li. When user clicking button "buy" it creates new li with in another div "ordersDiv" user can delete his purchase from cart by clicking "Remove" And this must remove li with matching id.
Code that creates purchase:

```
 $("#list").delegate("button",'click',function(){
        var  purchase = {id: null,name: null,price: null };
    var purchases = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++){
        if(this.id === phones[i].id){
          purchase.id =  phones[i].id;
            purchase.name = phones[i].name;
            purchase.price = phones[i].price;
            //break;
             purchases.push(purchase);
            console.log(purchases);
            $.each( purchases, function(i, purchase){
                purchases.push("<li id='"+ purchase.id +"'>" + purchase.id +
                "<br>" + purchase.name + "<br>" + "Price:" +purchase.price + "<br><button id='"+purchase.id+"' type='button' class='btn-default'>remove</button>" +"</li>" );

            });
            $('#ordersUl').append(purchases);
        }
    }
});
```

Code that supposed to remove li:

```
 $("#ordersCartDiv #ordersUl").delegate("button","click", function() {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(buttonId);
    //$("li[id=buttonId]").remove();
    $("#ordersUl").remove(buttonId);
    console.log("test");   // code indentation

});
```

Problem is that this code doesn't removes anything.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using ? If it is the latest one then 'delegate' has been depricated use 'on' instead.

Comment: You elements have same ID. That is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `remove` on button id.

```
$("# " + buttonId).remove();
```

No need to use `ordersUl` since `id` is unique(**?**).

If you don't have `id` unique:

```
$("#ordersUl #" + buttonId).remove(); // Will remove button inside #ordersUl
```

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 3):

you must pass a selector in remove function, like this:

```
$("#ordersUl").remove('#'+buttonId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ordersUl").remove("#"+buttonId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `remove` function on element

```
$("li#"+buttonId).remove();
```

But ID is supposed to be unique, so it is bad idea to use it in this way. Use `data-` attributes or classes.